# Generate a thumbnail for the first page of a PDF within a rails App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there anyway to generate a thumbnail image for the first page of an uploaded PDF file. I want to display this image along with the description (provided by the user) of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65250/convert-a-doc-or-pdf-to-an-image-and-display-a-thumbnail-in-ruby) looks like it'll do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an image processing library like ImageMagick to convert a PDF into an image.

Call out to the system with something like:

```
system("convert -size 150x150 /path/to/uploaded/document.pdf /path/to/thumbnail/file.png")
```