# How to convert PDF files to images using RMagick and Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, imagemagick, rmagick

I'd like to take a PDF file and convert it to images, each PDF page becoming a separate image.

"[Convert a .doc or .pdf to an image and display a thumbnail in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65250/convert-a-doc-or-pdf-to-an-image-and-display-a-thumbnail-in-ruby)" is a similar post, but it doesn't cover how to make separate images for each page.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) can do that with PDFs. Presumably [RMagick](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/) can do it too, but I'm not familiar with it.

The code from the post you linked to:

```
require 'RMagick'
pdf = Magick::ImageList.new("doc.pdf")
```

`pdf` is an `ImageList` object, which according to the [documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/ilist.html#array_methods) delegates many of its methods to `Array`. You should be able to iterate over `pdf` and call `write` to write the individual images to files.

Comment: No doubt... I'm just wondering if someone has some sample code.

Answer (score 58):

Using RMagick itself, you can create images for different pages:

```
require 'RMagick'
pdf_file_name = "test.pdf"
im = Magick::Image.read(pdf_file_name)
```

The code above will give you an array `arr[]`, which will have one entry for corresponding pages. Do this if you want to generate a JPEG image of the fifth page:

```
im[4].write(pdf_file_name + ".jpg")
```

But this will load the entire PDF, so it can be slow.

Alternatively, if you want to create an image of the fifth page and don't want to load the complete PDF file:

```
require 'RMagick'
pdf_file_name = "test.pdf[5]"
im = Magick::Image.read(pdf_file_name)
im[0].write(pdf_file_name + ".jpg")
```

Comment: Thanks for tip on the index in the path! Works great, even though it's a dirty hack ;)

Comment: This is great, but I got stuck for a long time not knowing I needed to "brew install ghostscript" as well to have the reader return more than an empty array. If you're an OSX user it might not come standard for you as well.

Comment: If you run into issues installing RMagick on OSX, read this to get things installed properly.

http://blog.paulopoiati.com/2013/01/28/installing-rmagick-in-mac-os-x-mountain-lion-with-homebrew/

Comment: Does not work for me. `im` is always an empty array in my case. Does it depend on the PDF?

Comment: Thanks @MatthewDuPont. I was getting empty array until I installed ghostscript.

Answer (score 2):

Since I can't find a way to deal with PDFs on a per-page basis in RMagick, I'd recommend first splitting the PDF into pages with [pdftk's](http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/) `burst` command, then dealing with the individual pages in RMagick. This is probably less performant than an all-in-one solution, but unfortunately no all-in-one solution presents itself.

There's also [PDF::Toolkit](http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/) for Ruby that hooks into pdftk but I've never used it.